# Filtering out the header and footer text using pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

I'm trying to get the text from a pdf document using pdfbox, the problem is I'm getting the header and footer text as well. Does anyone know if there's a way to filter that out? Maybe via some settings in TextPosition?

Comment: if you know where they are, use PDFTextStripperByArea. See also the ExtractTextByArea example.

Comment: @yaronbic The underlying question in Tilman's comment: how can headers and footers in your document be recognized? Are they tagged? Or at fixed positions? Or how else can they be recognized?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess that what I was asking. I don't the format very well and thought maybe there are some tags created for them when the pdf was generated